# Perl Regex extract substring because other substring exists

Tags: regex, perl, substring, conditional-statements

I need to extract a substring because another substring exists.  In the following example the word ERROR: proceeds the value 12345678.  I need the value 12345678.  In the second example ERROR: does not exist.  Therefore I need no result.  This is as far as I got:

```
ERROR:.*(\d)
```

> 20170808 ERROR: TXN 12345678 Request limit reached.
>
> 20170808 WARN: TXN 22345678 Pending expire.

If you are a regex guru then you know the above matches

> ERROR: TXN 12345678

and the group is only the digit 8. I need the whole number.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
ERROR:.*?(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Unecy2/1). Here, `.*?` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (as the `*?` is a lazy quantifier) and `(\d+)` will capture into Group 1 one or more digits.

Or, alternatively

```
ERROR:.*\D(\d+)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/Unecy2/2). Here, `.*\D` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars as *many* as possible (as `*` is a greedy quantifier), up to and including the last non-digit char (with `\D`) and then `(\d+)` will capture into Group 1 one or more digits.

Choose the pattern that best fits your scenario (the first is best if the number is the first group of digits after `ERROR:` and the second is best when the group of digits is the last one on a line).